# Podman container port forwarding has issue with secondary NIC

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, container, podman

My title may not be very clear

I have a server running CentOS 8:

`eth0` connects to subnet `10.0.3.0/24`, having IP `10.0.3.15`

`eth1` connects to subnet `10.0.103.0/24`, having IP `10.0.103.15`

As they have different gateways, I have IP rules:

```bash
$ ip rule list
0:  from all lookup local
1024:   from all to 172.16.5.0/24 lookup main
5000:   from 10.0.3.0/24 lookup t1
6000:   from 10.0.103.0/24 lookup t2
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

and route tables:

```bash
$ ip route show table t1
default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
10.0.3.1 dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 100

$ ip route show table t2
default via 10.0.103.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 101
10.0.103.1 dev eth1 proto static scope link metric 101
```

The above configuration should work fine at least for the host network, as I can ping both `10.0.3.15` and `10.0.103.15` from another server.

However when I create two redis containers with podman:

```
podman run -d --name redis1 -p 10.0.3.15:6379:6379 redis:apline
podman run -d --name redis2 -p 10.0.103.15:6379:6379 redis:apline
```

Only redis1 is accessible with `telnet [IP] 6379`,
`telnet 10.0.103.15 6379` gets nowhere, if I use tcpdump in the container redis2 I can't see anything coming in. However if I use `telnet 10.88.0.3 6379` while 10.88.0.3 is the internal IP of the redis2 container, I can connect to the redis from the host.

So I suspect maybe iptables NAT rules has issue, but this is my iptables:

```
$ iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes service portals */
CNI-HOSTPORT-DNAT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
CNI-HOSTPORT-MASQ  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* CNI portfwd requiring masquerade */
KUBE-POSTROUTING  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes postrouting rules */
CNI-97d3d333b7a91bb85f60a8e8  all  --  10.88.0.3            0.0.0.0/0            /* name: "podman" id: "f39d5e41593bc7f949db7bae5d06baa6d72606edec97a818a0842640ac557af5" */
CNI-0131634b11335acac74ae092  all  --  10.88.0.4            0.0.0.0/0            /* name: "podman" id: "65616612a5e5db3ef42cdae3cb40e65390bba2a826f0c7f097e3ed577e38590a" */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes service portals */
CNI-HOSTPORT-DNAT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain KUBE-MARK-DROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK or 0x8000

Chain KUBE-MARK-MASQ (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK or 0x4000

Chain KUBE-POSTROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* Kubernetes endpoints dst ip:port, source ip for solving hairpin purpose */ match-set KUBE-LOOP-BACK dst,dst,src
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            mark match ! 0x4000/0x4000
MARK       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK xor 0x4000
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT */ random-fully

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-LOAD-BALANCER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* Kubernetes service lb portal */ match-set KUBE-LOAD-BALANCER dst,dst
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* Kubernetes service cluster ip + port for masquerade purpose */ match-set KUBE-CLUSTER-IP src,dst
KUBE-NODE-PORT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set KUBE-CLUSTER-IP dst,dst
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set KUBE-LOAD-BALANCER dst,dst

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-MARK-DROP  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain KUBE-NODE-PORT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* Kubernetes nodeport TCP port with externalTrafficPolicy=local */ match-set KUBE-NODE-PORT-LOCAL-TCP dst
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* Kubernetes nodeport TCP port for masquerade purpose */ match-set KUBE-NODE-PORT-TCP dst

Chain KUBE-LOAD-BALANCER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* Kubernetes service load balancer ip + port with externalTrafficPolicy=local */ match-set KUBE-LOAD-BALANCER-LOCAL dst,dst
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain CNI-HOSTPORT-SETMARK (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* CNI portfwd masquerade mark */ MARK or 0x2000

Chain CNI-HOSTPORT-MASQ (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            mark match 0x2000/0x2000

Chain CNI-HOSTPORT-DNAT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
CNI-DN-97d3d333b7a91bb85f60a  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* dnat name: "podman" id: "f39d5e41593bc7f949db7bae5d06baa6d72606edec97a818a0842640ac557af5" */ multiport dports 6379
CNI-DN-0131634b11335acac74ae  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* dnat name: "podman" id: "65616612a5e5db3ef42cdae3cb40e65390bba2a826f0c7f097e3ed577e38590a" */ multiport dports 6379

Chain CNI-97d3d333b7a91bb85f60a8e8 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.88.0.0/16         /* name: "podman" id: "f39d5e41593bc7f949db7bae5d06baa6d72606edec97a818a0842640ac557af5" */
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !224.0.0.0/4          /* name: "podman" id: "f39d5e41593bc7f949db7bae5d06baa6d72606edec97a818a0842640ac557af5" */

Chain CNI-DN-97d3d333b7a91bb85f60a (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
CNI-HOSTPORT-SETMARK  tcp  --  10.88.0.0/16         10.0.103.15          tcp dpt:6379
CNI-HOSTPORT-SETMARK  tcp  --  127.0.0.1            10.0.103.15          tcp dpt:6379
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.103.15          tcp dpt:6379 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "iptables: "
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.103.15          tcp dpt:6379 to:10.88.0.3:6379

Chain CNI-0131634b11335acac74ae092 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.88.0.0/16         /* name: "podman" id: "65616612a5e5db3ef42cdae3cb40e65390bba2a826f0c7f097e3ed577e38590a" */
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !224.0.0.0/4          /* name: "podman" id: "65616612a5e5db3ef42cdae3cb40e65390bba2a826f0c7f097e3ed577e38590a" */

Chain CNI-DN-0131634b11335acac74ae (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
CNI-HOSTPORT-SETMARK  tcp  --  10.88.0.0/16         10.0.3.15            tcp dpt:6379
CNI-HOSTPORT-SETMARK  tcp  --  127.0.0.1            10.0.3.15            tcp dpt:6379
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.3.15            tcp dpt:6379 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "iptables: "
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.3.15            tcp dpt:6379 to:10.88.0.4:6379
```

As you can see, it's identical for 10.88.0.3 (redis2, which has issue) and 10.88.0.4 (redis1, which works)

and nothing special for the broken container in filter table:

```bash
$ iptables -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  169.254.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  30.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  11.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  9.0.0.0/8            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250
KUBE-NODE-PORT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes health check rules */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10250

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
CNI-FORWARD  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* CNI firewall plugin rules */
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000
DROP       all  -- !127.0.0.0/8          127.0.0.0/8          /* block incoming localnet connections */ ! ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-NODE-PORT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* Kubernetes health check node port */ match-set KUBE-HEALTH-CHECK-NODE-PORT dst

Chain CNI-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
CNI-ADMIN  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* CNI firewall plugin admin overrides */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.88.0.3            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.88.0.3            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.88.0.4            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.88.0.4            0.0.0.0/0

Chain CNI-ADMIN (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the logs for following rule in `dmesg`?

```
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.103.15          tcp dpt:6379 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "iptables: "
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, I can see logs coming into the host with this rule